# Shaking Hovering Menu bar

Tags: html, css

When you hovering the menu links, you may notice other links are shaking or moving when you hover one link, I know if I remove padding (10px 10px), it will be okay but hover background's brown become small. That's why I add padding to make it properly, only issue I have is I tried to remove shaking of other links?

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPwLRE)

```
(http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPwLRE)
```

Comment: can you provide a js?

Comment: NOTE:  I tried to add CodePen link in first attempt before posting, it is not working.  So I post it without providing CodePen link and then edit the post to add link, now working. How come?

Comment: @CarterB Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code.

Comment: I click CTRL K and then paste code between space commas, not working.  (sorry I am new here to understand StackOverflow). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added a padding property before mouse hover, the padding value same as `a:hover`

```
.topside-nav a {
    text-decoration: none; padding: 10px 10px; /*added padding */
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEWKmP

Comment: I want to add vote up but "Vote Up requires 15 reputation", sigh.

Comment: Bro, I want to check mark on your post, it should be only one mark. Both are similar great answers! :)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your code. Just add the same padding in li link.

```
.topside-nav li a{
     padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPGKWK